# EmberJS template component suddenly not rendering on page

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm following [this](https://guides.emberjs.com/release/tutorial/ember-cli/) Ember tutorial and I've suddenly run into an issue where my `rental-listing.hbs` template component stops rendering. It started when I began implementing the [map service](https://guides.emberjs.com/release/tutorial/service/).

I don't understand where this could be happening. I've copied the code from parts of the [GitHub repository](https://github.com/ember-learn/super-rentals) that I thought were relevant but to no avail.

I have a `rental.hbs` template that looks like so:

```
<div class="jumbo">
  <div class="right tomster"></div>
  <h2>Welcome!</h2>
  <p>We hope you find exactly what you're looking for in a place to stay.</p>
  {{#link-to "about" class="button"}}
    About Us
  {{/link-to}}
</div>
{{outlet}}
```

Which in turn has a template component called `rental-listing.hbs`:

```
<article class="listing">
  <a
    onclick={{action "toggleImageSize"}}
    class="image {{if this.isWide "wide"}}"
    role="button"
  >
    <img src={{this.rental.image}} alt="">
    <small>View Larger</small>
  </a>
  <div class="details">
    <h3>{{link-to this.rental.title "rentals.show" this.rental class=this.rental.id}}</h3>
    <div class="detail owner">
      <span>Owner:</span> {{this.rental.owner}}
    </div>
    <div class="detail type">
      <span>Type:</span> {{rental-property-type this.rental.category}} - {{this.rental.category}}
    </div>
    <div class="detail location">
      <span>Location:</span> {{this.rental.city}}
    </div>
    <div class="detail bedrooms">
      <span>Number of bedrooms:</span> {{this.rental.bedrooms}}
    </div>
  </div>
  <LocationMap @location={{this.rental.city}}/>
</article>
```

The only thing I have added to the above is the line `<LocationMap @location={{this.rental.city}}/>` but it still doesn't work if I remove it.

The console shows me no errors and I can actually see I am getting the three dummy objects I want from Mirage:

[image: Return]

So I'm definitely getting the objects and from what I see I'm doing everything necessary in the templates to render it but they aren't. Should I be looking somewhere else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you able to provide a link to your example? By having each piece of the ember application you mention it would be best to answer definitely. I can give a general answer with strategies for debugging the template.

The conventions behind ember.js make understanding the "whys" frustrating at first and possibly opaque. Ember's handlebars implementation governs how values are populated and accessed within templates using very specific rules. Ember treats templates (handlebars files) differently depending on whether it is for a route or component. Component's have an isolated context and must receive values by explicit [passing in](https://guides.emberjs.com/release/components/passing-properties-to-a-component/) or [dependency injection](https://guides.emberjs.com/release/applications/dependency-injection/#toc_ad-hoc-injections). Then, you can use such values in a  component's template by accessing those properties with `{{this.somePassedInValue}}`.

In the `super-rentals` app, it appears the rental index route invokes the components responsible for displaying the individual units. I found this in [`app/templates/rentals/index.hbs`](https://github.com/ember-learn/super-rentals/blob/master/app/templates/rentals/index.hbs#L4).

```
 <li><RentalListing @rental={{rentalUnit}} /></li>
```

The route template iterates over the list of `filteredResults`. Each of these is the `rentalUnit`. A good first step would be to use the `{{log}}` [helper](https://api.emberjs.com/ember/release/classes/Ember.Templates.helpers/methods/log?anchor=log) to print out that the value of `rentalUnit` to ensure it is what you expect.

Alternatively, you could try cloning https://github.com/ember-learn/super-rentals and applying the changes you want to make step by step from the master branch. By doing so, you could easily undo a single change to see what caused something to not show up as expected.

Answer (score 0):

```
<LocationMap @location={{this.rental.city}}/> 
to be written as below
<LocationMap @location={{this.rentals.city}}/>
```

may be typo error. 
also repeat this for there place in that template.
Because the model name in the console is `rentals`  not `rental`

Comment: I don't think it is a typo actually. If you look at the example structure in the [canonical example](https://github.com/ember-learn/super-rentals/blob/master/app/templates/components/rental-listing.hbs#L25). The route invokes the component [here](https://github.com/ember-learn/super-rentals/blob/master/app/templates/rentals/index.hbs#L4) which populates `rental` for use within the component's template.